# Objective-C Version comparison

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing version numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160216/comparing-version-numbers)
>   [How to use compare on a version number where theres less parts in one number in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308659/how-to-use-compare-on-a-version-number-where-theres-less-parts-in-one-number-in)

I am attempting to sort an `NSMutableArray` of custom objects based on a property called `referenceID` which essentially resembles a version number.

It seems that treating `referenceID` as an `NSNumber` and sorting it using `compareTo:` almost gets it right, but where it breaks is cases such as:

```
Result:           Should Be:
1.1.1             1.1.1
1.1.10            1.1.2
1.1.2             ...
...               1.1.9
1.1.9             1.1.10

(Where ... is 1.1.2 through 1.1.9)
```

Are there any built in functions that will sort this properly? Or should I get started writing the sorting algorithm?

Comment: Also checkout [How to use compare on a version number where theres less parts in one number in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308659/how-to-use-compare-on-a-version-number-where-theres-less-parts-in-one-number-in)

Comment: Ah, thank you. My Overflow-searching skills need some work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your reference id is a string, you can use `localizedStandardCompare:`, which compares numbers in strings according to their numerical value.

Example (with `sortedArrayUsingComparator`, because that is used by the OP in his comment):

```
NSArray *versions = @[@"2.1.1.1", @"2.10.1", @"2.2.1"];
NSArray *sorted = [versions sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *s1, NSString *s2) {
    return [s1 localizedStandardCompare:s2];
}];
NSLog(@"%@", sorted);
```

Output:

```
2012-11-29 23:51:28.962 test27[1962:303] (
    "2.1.1.1",
    "2.2.1",
    "2.10.1"
)
```

Comment: he has version numbers though.. dot separated versions of different length. does the function do that?

Comment: @Daij-Djan: Yes, that works with numbers of different length.

Comment: Perhaps I'm doing something wrong here, but I'm still getting the same results as above with this:

[standards sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Standard *s1, Standard *s2)
                                    {
                                        return [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", s1.referenceID] localizedStandardCompare:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", s2.referenceID]];

Comment: @Martin R : Cool didnt know that one :) Thanks useful

Comment: @KyleBanks: I have added example code using `sortedArrayUsingComparator`, does that help?

Comment: why not sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];? is that somehow bad.. its shorter... (honest sub-question of mine)

Comment: @Daij-Djan: Because the OP's array does not contain strings, but `Standard` objects which have a `referenceID` property, see his above comment.

Comment: Sample output using this code: 

 2.1.1.1, 

 2.10.1, 

 2.2.1.

 It does however work properly on the final point of the version number.

Comment: @KyleBanks: That is strange ... I have used your data in my test program, and it produces the expected result. See my updated answer, it is copy/paste from my actual output.

Comment: This is very strange, I just copied your above code directly into my project, and I get the same result. However sorting based off the `Standard` referenceID, the results are off. 

I've accepted your answer because clearly this does work, but something is wrong with my own code that I will need to debug. Thanks!

Comment: @KyleBanks: You are welcome. - Perhaps the conversion from reference id to string does not give the expected result? (Just an idea.)

Comment: @MartinR I wish it was that simple, but alas that was my first thought as well. I'll keep digging.

Comment: I don't think this is reliable. From Apple's documentation: "The exact sorting behavior of this method is different under different locales and may be changed in future releases." See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/localizedStandardCompare:

Answer (score 0):

sort it with a block

---

```
@autoreleasepool {
    //in this example, array of NSStrings
    id array = @[@"1.1.1",@"2.2",@"1.0",@"1.1.0.1",@"1.1.2.0", @"1.0.3", @"2.1.1.1", @"2.1.1", @"2.1.10"];

    //block
    id sorted = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSArray *comps1 = [obj1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        NSArray *comps2 = [obj2 componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

        //get ints from comps
        int res1 = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<comps1.count; i++) {
            res1 += [comps1[i] intValue] * (4 - i);
        }
        int res2 = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<comps2.count; i++) {
            res2 += [comps2[i] intValue] * (4 - i);
        }

        return res1<res2 ? NSOrderedAscending : res1>res2 ? NSOrderedSame : NSOrderedDescending;
    }];

    NSLog(@"%@", sorted);
}
```